# Find function type from list of points

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

I have a list of points, and plotting them on a graph it looks like a Log/esponential graph.. But none of the generic formulas give me a function that returns all the points. ($y=a*b^x+k$, $y=log b(x-a)$)

How can I, strating from the given points, find the function?

[image]

Edit:

The values are in mm, and are a measurement. In reallife the x values go from 0 to 800. So an aproximation that returns values within a tollerance of +/-3mm in the range from 0 to 800 is good enough. 
The Y values are the values for this specific machine. In real life each machine will have different Y values, and I will also have only 3 points. (for example 0,300,600)
What I would need is a way to find a function with 3 given points.

Comment: Does the function need to match the points exactly (resulting potentially in a very complicated expression), or is an approximation alright (much simpler expression) ?

Comment: You probably won't get an exact fit to these exact values so trivially. Do you have an error tolerance for your function estimate

Comment: The values are in millimeters. i have a tollerance of +/- 3 mm.

Comment: I just found another point: -6000/100

Comment: @MattiP. in addition the x values in my reallife scenario go only from 0 to 800. I only added the other points to find the trend..

Comment: What are you modelling? Where does the data come from? Do you have a theory that could help us model the data? In other words, is there a reason why the data should be logarithmic, etc. ?

Comment: there is a camera at ABOUT 1500 from the floor. It takes pictures of crate stacks from above. The crate stacks vary in height and have a projected laser line projected on them, The laser is parallel to the camera axis, and based on the crate height the position inside the picture will change. I make 3 measurements to teach in the system and it should then calculate the height based on the position of the laser